# What is the rule of thumb for using @property(copy) vs. @property(retain)?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I wonder if there is a rule of thumb you follow, when deciding whether or not a given property in ObjectiveC should be a `retain` or `copy`?

How do you decide which it should be?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Typically you use `copy` for safety with classes which have mutable variants, like `NSString`, `NSArray`, the other collection classes, etc. To see why, consider what happens here...

Once upon a time,

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property (retain) NSString *happyString;
- (void)rejoice;
@end
```

Then one day,

```
- (void)bigBadMethod {
    MyClass *myObject = [[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSMutableString *theString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"I'm happy!"];
    myObject.happyString = theString; // this is allowed because NSMutableString inherits from NSString
    [myObject rejoice]; // prints "I'm happy!"
```

when suddenly...

```
    [theString setString:@"BRAAAAIIINNNSSSSS"];
    [myObject rejoice]; // prints "BRAAAAIIINNNSSSSS"
}
```

And you wouldn't want that, would you? So use `@property (copy)` if you don't want to get mutated while you're not looking!

Comment: +1 If you enable zombies, then rejoicing *should* print "BRAAAAIIINNNSSSSS" ;)

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, `assign` vs `retain` vs `copy` determines how the synthesized accessors interact with the Objective-C memory management scheme:

- `assign` is the default and simply performs a variable assignment
- `retain` specifies the new value should be sent -retain on assignment and the old value sent release
- `copy` specifies the new value should be sent -copy on assignment and the old value sent release.

Remember that `retain` is done on the created object (it increases the reference count) whereas `copy` creates a new object. The difference, then, is whether you want to add another retain to the object or create an entirely new object.

Comment: While you're technically correct, the OP was asking *why* to use each option, not *what* the options are. :)