# Multi-dimensional data objects

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm in the process of deciding on the best way to organize data in my app. I'm trying to decide if I need to be concerned with the memory and processing requirements for a couple different styles for data organization using `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`, and which of these methods would be better.

Consider this example:

You have an ordered list of individual people and information associated with each person. Ordered for some arbitrary reason that is not relevant here.

The list, as it is ordered, is an `NSArray`. You have two options, the way I see it:

- Fill this array with NSDictionaries. Inside each dictionary is the information for that one single person. I.E. a key for "name," "address," "email," or whatever you want.
- Or, your NSArray contains just a list of unique identifiers as `NSString`s (an array of keys). Then, you have separate NSDictionaries for each info item, like one dictionary for "email addresses," another for "names," etc, and for each dictionary your unique identifier is the dictionary key.

Is there any more "elegant" a solution than either of these, and would either be preferable over the other for the app's runtime demands?

I come from a PHP background where creating a multidimensional array is real easy and intuitive, where you can do simple things like:

`echo "The second person's name is ".$person[2][name];`

Figuring out the best practice in Objective C has been a bit challenging for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second suggestion (separate dictionaries) seems awfully unintuitive to me. Plus, you won't end up seeing much of a difference in memory usage between your two options. An array of dictionaries is fine.

The alternative option I would suggest would be to actually have a class, for example:

```
@interface Person : NSObject
@property (copy) NSString *name;
@property (copy) NSString *address;
@property (copy) NSString *email;
@end
```

This could be potentially more efficient than using dictionaries, since each Person object would have exactly the storage required for those three fields.

Comment: As you might have hundreds of people, and they need to be ordered, with this method you would still have an `NSArray` of `Person` objects; I wonder if there is any difference in memory overhead doing this versus the array of dictionaries?

Comment: The array will only hold pointers to the objects it contains; the size of those objects themselves won't affect the array.

Comment: would the memory footprint be the same if I chose `(retain)` for each synthesized property, but released the original object that was added to the Person object? for example, `person.name=aString;[aString release];` ?

Comment: Yes, but generally it's a good idea to use `(copy)` for objects which have mutable subclasses — see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115337/what-is-the-rule-of-thumb-for-using-propertycopy-vs-propertyretain/7115384#7115384).

Comment: since `copy` is essentially using more memory, then it would seem more memory-wise to just `retain` if you are responsible not to get into the situation described in your other answer; otherwise, you end up taking up twice the amount of memory, right?

Comment: Yes, assuming `copy` actually makes a duplicate object in memory. For immutable objects it might be optimized to just `retain`, but that's an implementation detail, and yes, you are correct in general.

Comment: doesn't `copy` by definition *always* make a duplicated object in memory (for mutable objects)?

Comment: What I'm saying is, NSMutableString's `-copy` will definitely return a new object, while NSString's `-copy` *might* be optimized to just `-retain` — since you can't mutate it, there's no reason you have to create a new object. From the NSCopying docs: "The exact meaning of “copy” can vary from class to class, but a copy must be a functionally independent object with values identical to the original at the time the copy was made."

Comment: i appreciate your help and explanation on this discussion that went slightly off topic but is quite useful in its own right. cheers.